# Bucle Python ficheros, modifcar y guardar

Tags: python-3.x

Buenas a ver si me podéis echar una mano con esto que todavía me lió un poco con estos de los bucles y estoy empezando en python, estoy leyendo un directorio con 20 ficheros .txt la idea es abrir cada fichero y a cada uno añadirle un texto y que los 20 ficheros tengan ese texto y una vez realzado la modificación guardar de nuevo cada fichero tendría que obtener otra vez 20 otros ficheros con la frase ya añadida. Me he quedado atascado ya en este trozo es lo que tengo escrito por ahora también la parte de guardar el fichero pero no consigo tampoco hacerla en bucle para que me cierre uno por uno la modificación. Solo lo consigo hacer individualmente.

```
import glob
import re
import os



os.chdir("Prueba/")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    print(file)

    f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')

    save = f.read()
    print(save)


    f.close()
```

Comment: Hola Alfonso, a ve si me aclaro... ¿el texto se añade al final del contenido que ya tiene cada archivo o en otra posición?¿Se modifican in-place? ¿o se crean nuevos archivos con distinto nombre o en otro directorio?

Comment: Buenas FJSevilla, la idea es crear un fichero nuevo con distinto nombre con ese contenido añadido. ejemplo fichero1 y el nuevo seria fichero1add y asi con todos los que se recorran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ciclo ya lo tienes y la lectura del archivo también, te quedaría abrir otro archivo general el nuevo nombre y escribir el contenido del archivo original más el texto nuevo:

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path

add_string = "\nStack Overflow en Español"


for path in glob.glob("Prueba/*.txt"):
    path = Path(path)
    new_path = Path.joinpath(path.parent, f"{path.stem}add{path.suffix}")

    with open(path, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as orig,\
         open(new_path, "w", encoding='utf-8-sig') as final:
        final.write(orig.read())
        final.write(add_string)
```